# How to fix Prestashop front office, 500 internal server error?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I was setting up a prestashop theme, and this error came out of somewhere. Can you suggest me how to fix this?

**Debug Mode View:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to be an issue with your module called Google Map Store Page. Specifically, the error is on line 277 of this file: https://github.com/ArnaudDx/Google-map-store-page-prestashop-1.7/blob/master/storeggmap/storeggmap.php.

Is this a module that you need to use? If not, disabling/deleting it should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks mate! It removed it. Then there was an error in another module too, but I was able to fix it. It works now. Also, are you a Prestashop developer? If yes, can you suggest me some YouTube links or other non-official resources to study prestashop architecture?? Thanks :)

Comment: Brilliant! :) I have only ever built one website with Prestashop and it was a massive pain for things like this haha.